# Adding YTD, YTG column to Excel OLAP Pivot

Tags: excel, mdx, olap

I have an Excel pivot table connecting to an OLAP cube with a report looking something like

```
           Jan   Feb   Mar .........Dec
Revenue     55    32    65..........45
```

I'd like to add extra columns YTD and YTG etc.  These are already calculated measures in my cube, but when they are added to the Pivot table, not surprisingly, the months are repeated for each measure.

I just need the columns at the end like

```
           Jan   Feb   Mar .........Dec   YTD   YTG
Revenue     55    32    65..........45    654    30
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is "YTG"? So you actually just want YTD at December? Which is just a Total column? What sort of measures are you dealing with - additive ones?

Comment: How are `YTG` and `YTG` defined in your cube? Are they measures? Or are they members of the date dimension, or of a utility dimension?

Comment: YTG is 'Year to Go' and is basically [Total Year]-YTD.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution although an inelegant one. Basically to create calculated members for Jan-Dec and uses these as columns in the report.

As I say, inelegant but client likes it.